# Where do I find the @Guice Annotation

Tags: guice, testng

I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664233/use-verify-on-mocked-with-mockito-objects-inject-by-guice) about the @Guice Annotation. It might be a good exchange for the custom GuiceTestRunner I built.

Where can I find it? Its not in my classpath ...

Thanks

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't precise enough: I use ivy, and I have guice, guice-servlet, guice-assistedinject, guice-throwingproviders in my dependencies (and in my classpath). "Guice" is the class I use to createInjectors.
I dont see the @Guice(modules=....) Annotation mentioned in the referenced Question. So I wonder: where does the Annotation come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete class Name is org.testng.annotations.Guice, and it's available in testng 6.3

The maven dependency is =>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Correct, it's a TestNG feature to make integration of TestNG and Guice easier. Upvoted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was on the wrong trail, searching it in the guice-extensions directly. Certainly will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Maven or Ivy or one of the other automated dependency management tools (if you were, you wouldn't be asking this question) you should try the relevant project's [download page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list).

Comment: Seriously, did you even try using Google?

Comment: Enlighten me! Google "@Guice Annotation" ... I am not looking for Guice, but @Guice